# How do I add a HTML E-Mail signature to my LOTUS NOTES version 7.0.2

Tags: lotus-notes

I use Lotus Notes at my workplace and am having problems inserting a email signature to it, even the IS people therecan't figure it out, version is 7.0.2 any help would be great.          THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a full HTML file containing your signature - name it whatever you like.

In Lotus Notes then open your Mail, click `Tools` - `Preferences` - `Mail` tab - `Signature` tab, and there you have a button for locating that HTML file you created before.

That worked in my office, but I can't remember for which version that was.